Bounds on the length of simple paths in DFAs resulting from the powerset construction of an NFA
In general, a DFA $P(A)$ resulting from the powerset construction of an $m$-states NFA $A$ may have $2^m$ states, and a simple path traversing all these states is often there.
However, I cannot find in the literature (nor on my own) conditions under which simple paths in the $P(A)$ remain short, i.e. polynomial in $m$. For example, is there any structural property of NFAs (such as low cycle rank, unambiguity, or others) which guarantees every simple path in the DFA has polynomial length?
And what if I look at simple paths in the minimal DFA recognizing $L(A)$, instead of $P(A)$?

There exists an $(n + 1)$-state UFA with cycle rank 1 for the language $1\Sigma^{n-1}$. This language always has a simple path of length $2^n$ (given by an order $n$ de Bruijn sequence) in any corresponding DFA, constructed using the powerset construction or otherwise.

Thanks! Maybe I don't get your example. For the language $1\Sigma^{n-1}$, why is a DFA with $n+1$ states not enough?

Sorry, I meant $\Sigma^*1\Sigma^{n-1}$ in which case you need to keep track of the last $n$ characters.

Thanks, this makes perfect sense now!
